# Create multiple rows based on 1 column

Tags: sql

I currently have a table with a quantity in it.

```
ID       Code            Quantity
1        A               1
2        B               3
3        C               2
4        D               1
```

Is there anyway to write a sql statement that would get me

```
ID       Code            Quantity
1        A               1
2        B               1
2        B               1
2        B               1
3        C               1
3        C               1
4        D               1
```

I need to break out the quantity and have that many number of rows

Thanks

Comment: Smells like an XY problem. Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: `join` to a table with numbers `1..n` in it using `on n between 1 and  quantity`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option using a `numbers` table to `join` to:

```
with numberstable as (
    select 1 AS Number
    union all
    select Number + 1 from numberstable where Number<100
    )
select t.id, t.code, 1 
from yourtable t 
    join numberstable n on t.quantity >= n.number 
order by t.id
```

- [Online Demo](https://rextester.com/TVM58482)

Please note, depending on which database you are using, this may not be the correct approach to creating the `numbers` table.  This works in most databases supporting `common table expressions`.  But the key to the answer is the `join` and the `on` criteria.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to generate an array with X elements (where X is the quantity). So for rows

```
ID       Code            Quantity
1        A               1
2        B               3
3        C               2
```

you would get

```
ID       Code            Quantity   ArrayVar
1        A               1          [1]
2        B               3          [1,2,3]
3        C               2          [2]
```

using a sequence function (e.g, in PrestoDB, sequence(start, stop) -> array(bigint))

Then, unnest the array, so for each ID, you get a X rows, and set the quantity to 1. Not sure what SQL distribution you're using, but this should work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use connect by statement to cross join tables in order to get your desired output.
check my solution it works pretty robust.

```
select 
  "ID", 
  "Code", 
  1 QUANTITY 
from Table1, table(cast(multiset
(select level from dual 
 connect by level <= Table1."Quantity") as  sys.OdciNumberList));
```